# Best way to have multiple "submit" buttons in a form?

Tags: php, html, forms

Let's say I've got a simple form (but it's fairly long).

This form submits user data into a database, and after the first submission, it is rarely (99.99%) ever edited in full again, only one section at a time.

I don't want a user to have to scroll halfway down to the section they need, then have to scroll the same distance again to submit it.

```
<form>

    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

That's the "VERY" basic structure of it. Would is be considered a decent practice to do something like this

```
<form>

    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="afterFormSubmit"/>

</form>
```

I'm not sure if there is a 'better' way to do this, or if this is one of the better ways to get it accomplished?

Comment: Are you ruling out using AJAX-methods to make this a much better UI?

Comment: No - I'd consider getting an AJAX approach in here, I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Truth be told, I'd rather not - but I really don't mind, especially if it's for a significantly better UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you do this with AJAX the best way is with two forms. You can submit using an ajax request two different things within the same form.

Or if you want to have the same form with submit buttons on each section the just a submit link like so

```
<a href="JavaScript:submit_form();">Submit</a>
```

this way no matter what section they are on the submit works for the form you want it to.

another option could be to split it up using tabs i.e. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

you could have your 1 submit outside the tab area. more information here: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/02/18/How-to-deal-with-large-webforms.aspx

Comment: information on dealing with large forms http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sensibleforms

Answer (score 2):

put your submit button on a none-scrollable view.

```
<form>
  <input type='text'/>
  ...
  ...
  <input type='submit' style="display:fixed; top:100px; left:200px;" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, instead of having only a `<form>`, I think you should have a different form for each submit button you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did that once for one client who needed just a simple calendar with Xs

I've put a submit button on each calendar and all those were embed into 1 form that php_self

I big procedural file, even though I prefer OOP